# ninja WebRtc build error :ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: webrtc, ninja

WSL + Ubuntu18.04 + webrtc

This project is proper functioning in Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't with WSL;

gn command:

```
gn gen out/SDK --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm" is_debug=true rtc_use_h264=true use_openh264=true rtc_libvpx_build_vp9=false rtc_build_libvpx=true rtc_include_tests=false rtc_include_ilbc=false rtc_include_pulse_audio=false ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"'
```

error Info :

```
    ninja: Entering directory `out/SDK'
 [2138/5820] ACTION 


    //api/video:video_frame_enums(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
FAILED: gen/api/video/video_frame_enums.srcjar
python ../../build/android/gyp/java_cpp_enum.py --depfile gen/api/video/video_frame_enums.d --srcjar=gen/api/video/video_frame_enums.srcjar ../../api/video/video_codec_type.h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../build/android/gyp/java_cpp_enum.py", line 437, in <module>
    DoMain(sys.argv[1:])
  File "../../build/android/gyp/java_cpp_enum.py", line 429, in DoMain
    for output_path, data in DoGenerate(input_paths):
  File "../../build/android/gyp/java_cpp_enum.py", line 329, in DoGenerate
    source_path)
Exception: No enums found in ../../api/video/video_codec_type.h
Did you forget prefixing enums with "// GENERATED_JAVA_ENUM_PACKAGE: foo"?
[2140/5820] ACTION //api:rtp_parameters_enums(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
FAILED: gen/api/rtp_parameters_enums.srcjar
python ../../build/android/gyp/java_cpp_enum.py --depfile gen/api/rtp_parameters_enums.d --srcjar=gen/api/rtp_parameters_enums.srcjar ../../api/rtp_parameters.h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../build/android/gyp/java_cpp_enum.py", line 437, in <module>
    DoMain(sys.argv[1:])
  File "../../build/android/gyp/java_cpp_enum.py", line 429, in DoMain
    for output_path, data in DoGenerate(input_paths):
  File "../../build/android/gyp/java_cpp_enum.py", line 329, in DoGenerate
    source_path)
Exception: No enums found in ../../api/rtp_parameters.h
Did you forget prefixing enums with "// GENERATED_JAVA_ENUM_PACKAGE: foo"?
[2143/5820] CC obj/third_party/libaom/libaom_intrinsics_neon/av1_inv_txfm_neon.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How can I change it to compile properly?